# ROS 1 Stereo image pairs splitter node migration to ROS 2 Galactic

Tags: publisher, colcon, cv-bridge, image-transport, ros-galactic

I have modified the ROS 1 source from this [repo](https://github.com/dbc/side_x_side_stereo) to use in ROS 2 galactic

While I am able to satisfy the package dependencies, I'm having issues with the following code:

```
        cv_bridge::CvImage cvImage;
        
        cvImage.encoding = msg->encoding;
        cvImage.header.frame_id = msg->header.frame_id;
        cvImage.header.stamp = msg->header.stamp;
        if (pub_img_l->get_subscription_count() > 0
            || pub_cam_info_l->get_subscription_count() > 0)
        {

            cvImage.image = use_scaled ? leftScaled : leftImage;
            //TODO:fix
            img = cvImage.toImageMsg();
            img_l->publish(*img);
            cinfomsg->header.stamp = img->header.stamp;
            cinfomsg->header.frame_id = img ->header.frame_id;
            pub_cam_info_l->publish(cinfomsg);
        }
        if (pub_img_r->get_subscription_count() > 0
            || pub_cam_info_r->get_subscription_count() > 0)
        {
            
            cvImage.image = use_scaled ? rightScaled : rightImage;
            //TODO:fix
            img = cvImage.toImageMsg();
            img_r->publish(*img);
            cinfomsg->header.stamp = img->header.stamp;
            cinfomsg->header.frame_id = img->header.frame_id;
            pub_cam_info_r->publish(cinfomsg);
```

Specifically colcon fails with:

`error: no matching function for call to rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> > >::publish(sensor_msgs::msg::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >::SharedPtr&)’ 203 |             pub_cam_info_r->publish(cinfomsg);`

And it also fails on publishing the actual image as well:

`error: no matching function for call to rclcpp::Publisher<image_transport::Publisher>::publish(std::__shared_ptr_access<sensor_msgs::msg::Image_<std::allocator<void> >, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>::element_type&)’ 200 |             img_r->publish(*img);`

Now for reference here is the applicable constructor code:

```
            auto imaget_ = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("image publisher");
            this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>("input_image_topic", 10, std::bind(&SplitImagePair::imageCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));

            auto left_cinfo_ = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("camera_linfo");
            auto right_cinfo_ = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("camera_rinfo");

            image_transport::ImageTransport it(imaget_);

            // Create pubs
            auto img_l = imaget_->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>("left_output_image_topic", 1);
            auto img_r = imaget_->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>("right_output_image_topic", 1);

            auto pub_cam_info_l = left_cinfo_->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::CameraInfo>("left_camera_info_topic", 1);
            auto pub_cam_info_r = right_cinfo_->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::CameraInfo>("right_camera_info_topic", 1);

        }
        ~SplitImagePair(){}
        
        void timer_callback()
        {

            // Get params
            std::string inputImageTopic = this->get_parameter("input_image_topic").as_string();
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "input topic to stereo splitter=%s\n", inputImageTopic.c_str());

            std::string left_output_image_topic = this->get_parameter("left_output_image_topic").as_string();
            std::string right_output_image_topic = this->get_parameter("right_output_image_topic").as_string();
            std::string left_camera_info_topic = this->get_parameter("left_camera_info_topic").as_string();
            std::string right_camera_info_topic = this->get_parameter("right_camera_info_topic").as_string();
            std::string outputWidth = this->get_parameter("output_width").as_string();
            std::string outputHeight = this->get_parameter("output_height").as_string();

        }

    private:
        //Publisher shared ptrs (formerly node handles)
        rclcpp::Publisher<camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager>::SharedPtr left_cinfo_, right_cinfo_;
        rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::CameraInfo>::SharedPtr pub_cam_info_l, pub_cam_info_r;
        rclcpp::Publisher<image_transport::Publisher>::SharedPtr img_l, img_r;
        rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::SharedPtr pub_img_l, pub_img_r;
        rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::SharedPtr input_image_;

        // callback funtion declaration
        void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr & msg);
        rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_ptr_;
```